# Facebook page in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, facebook, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in my application where I 'm loading the facebook profile of my application. I am using facebook's single sign on SDK(Graph API). And I logged in into facebook in the Safari in background using my application. But When I try loadmy game profile in my application web view still I could see "Log In" and "Sign Up" buttons. 
I tried setting cookies, main document URL and relative URL too but no use.
I am adding here my code too here,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/myapp" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.facebook.com"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;

    if(url)
        request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSArray * availableCookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.facebook.com"]];
    NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:availableCookies];
    if(request)
    {
        [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
        [request setMainDocumentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.facebook.com"]];
        [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];//login.facebook.com
        [mWebView loadRequest:request];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running into the situation I describe in the answer on this page:

[Facebook iOS SDK not storing cookies for access](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6964721/facebook-ios-sdk-not-storing-cookies-for-access/7124238#7124238)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. It means we can not fetch the cookies of facebook.

Comment: As far as I can tell, on iOs, you cannot get the cookies that the Facebook app is using, or that mobile Safari is using.  If you get an access token without opening either of the other two (such as if they are not available), the cookies will be local to your app and you can use them.  It is possible to modify the Facebook iOS SDK slightly to force this situation.  Doing so means, however, that you give up single sign on for users of the official Facebook app.

Comment: Doesn't this enable a malicious use of facebook.com cookies? An app developer could seemingly ask the user to "login with facebook", capture facebook.com cookies when login is successful and use them to act on behalf of the user. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The cookies expire when the session is closed, but theoretically, yes, you used to be able to do that, at least until the session closed.  FB Login now uses the Safari View Controller as of iOS 9, rather than a local UIWebview.  And you can't get those cookies.  Not sure if you can still force a local UIWebview login.